# Alias for files in Mac and images - how to get images to work as alias/symlink?

Tags: html, alias, symlink

I have three folders within the directory **mytesthtml**:

testdir1

testdir2

testdir3 (alias of testdir1)

and three files:

index.html
test.css
mypic.jpg (alias)
test11.css (alias)

The alias for the jpeg file within the directory does not display it in HTML in my test page:

```html
<TITLE>Washington D.C.</TITLE>
<head>
<style>
body {
width: 400px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
</style>
</head>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Washington_Montage_2016.png/275px-Washington_Montage_2016.png">

<H1>This is Washington D.C</h1>

<p><img src="federal_triangle.jpg"></p>
<p><img src="testdir1/abelincoln.jpg"></p>
<p><img src="testdir3/abelincoln.jpg"></p>
<p>By Jon Doe</p>
<p>test</p>
```

The HTML works OK, although the alias does not work for testdir3.

Would symlinks work better in some cases, for a HTML file in testdir1, instead of doing:

When should I symlink and when should I use aliases in my test webdesign projects on Mac or Linux, before doing this for real?

This is plain HTML files, so no Apache rules etc. - it's a folder for testing website design on Desktop on Catalina on Mac.

Comment: You should run your tests from a local webserver. It's like real easy froma  mac to set up an Apache2 server.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using a different browser & try closing and restarting the browser the alias would not display in.**

I encountered the problem on a new Mac running macOS Ventura in its Safari browser.

I pasted the link to the file using the alias jpeg into Google Chrome Canary, the jpeg with the alias displayed just fine.

Next, I pasted the link into the Brave browser, again it displayed just fine.

Next, I explored Safari's settings.  Under advanced, I changed the Default encoding from "Western (ISO Latin 1)" to "Unicode (UTF-8)" When I refreshed Safari the image with the alias still did not display. But when I closed Safari completely and started it again: the image with the alias displayed just fine.  I changed back to "Western (ISO Latin 1)" shut Safari down and started it again.  The image continued to display just fine with the original default encoding that the problem first occurred.  So, the solution could have involved shutting Safari down and starting it again or changing the encoding.

I tried to duplicate the problem for more investigation by creating an alias link to a different image, the other image displayed just fine in Safari so I was unable to duplicate the problem.

I create my alias links with terminal in the directory I wish to use them like this:

ln -s pathToTheActualImage/actualImage.jpg aliasImage.jpg